# Karate - Overview reporting without parallel runner

Tags: karate

I have tests which can't be run parallel but need to be run sequentially , So I have individual runners with me .

But I am not getting an overview report for the same in the surefire-reports , I am only getting step by step report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really clear. Do you want to run every test sequencially? If yes :

```
`Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 1, karateOutputPath);`
```

If you want to run features in parallel but for need the scenarios inside a feature to run sequencially :
https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse

And if you want some features to run sequencially, and some to run in parallel, while still having a single report, you'll have to launch two runners, one in parallel, one with a single thread, with a specified tag. And then compile both reports into one. Example with Cucumber report :

`generateReport(resultsParallel.getReportDir(), resultsNotParallel.getReportDir());`